# Get access to Heroku remote

Tags: git, heroku

I've been working on a project which uses Heroku, but until recently I wasn't able to access the Heroku remote.

Now I obtained permissions however.

I got an email from Heroku saying I should run:

```
heroku git:clone -a myAppName
```

I don't want to clone the repository again, I just want to add the existing Heroku repository as a new remote.

I tried:

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:myAppName.git
```

However, I am getting:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'XX.XX.XX.XXX' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Which seems normal since I haven't actually logged in to Heroku, so they shouldn't allow me to see the repository.

So how can I add Heroku as a remote?
Do I need to login from terminal?

Comment: Have you added your `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (or it's analog) to you Heroku account?

Comment: BTW, you can user `heroku git:remote` (inside project's dir) to add Heroku remotes if you have Heroku CLI installed

Comment: If I do 'heroku git:remote --app myAppName' it will not connect me to my app on heroku even if I login. I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

for existing repository

in terminal type 
$ heroku login -i
  enter your email and password then

$ heroku git:remote -a example

[image]